# What is a parameter of type const pointer const reference? (const X* const & p)

Tags: c++, constants

I found a function in our team's code that has the following signature:

```
struct Bar;

void foo(const Bar *const &p)
{
    // Read some data from Bar.
}
```

I tried reading up on const correctness, but I cannot determine if this is intended or if it is possible to simplify the case.

To me this sounds like a constant reference to a constant pointer. But wouldn't it be easier to just pass the constant pointer itself?

Comment: A pointer has 2 kind of `const`, the pointer itself can be `const` and the pbject it points to can be `const`

Comment: @super I think OP understand it, that's why he ask *But wouldn't it be easier to just pass the constant pointer itself?*

Comment: That reference can be saved somewhere to observe changes of pointer value later.

Comment: That protects implementor from being tempted to modify the pointer. Prototypes are likes contracts, this one is: take that pointer as-is and don't change it neither what it points to.

Comment: That would translate to "constant pointer to constant reference". References can't be changed after they have been initialized. I don't think it makes sense to talk about a constant reference. You can write Bar* const p for a constant pointer to p or const Bar* p for a pointer to constant p(which is the same with Bar const* p).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass pointers to objects by constant reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071305/pass-pointers-to-objects-by-constant-reference-in-c)

Comment: Passing a pointer by reference is probably of no usage in common implementations, but as a semantic point of view these are different things. As a reference you "really" pass the pointer itself, as a pointer a copy of it. It may happens that the compiler would be able to find situation where this differs and may optimize something better.

Comment: So the alternative would be to make it `foo(const Bar* const p)` as stated here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ptr-vs-ptr-const ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right. As long as no one does some nasty `const_cast<const Bar *&p>` inside this function this can be simplified to:

```
struct Bar;

void foo(const Bar *p)
{
    // Read some data from Bar.
}
```

Comment: And why not make it `const Bar * const p`?

Comment: As long you pass pointer by value it doesn't really change anything. If you don't intend to use it as local variable you can use `const Bar * const p`

Comment: Alright, I understand. The pointer itself doesn't have to be const, because you just use it in that function. Otherwise people might change p itself, but that's their choice inside of that function. The pointer itself is a copy to the same const object.